# How can I schedule a future TFS release with approval, with approval being BEFORE the scheduled release time?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

For example:
I want to schedule a release for 1am, but for obvious reasons I don't want the approver to need to be awake at 1am to click "approve".

By default, if I schedule it for 1am, TFS doesn't send the approval email until 1am.

The only way I've found to do this is super risky; 
Start a release right now, and make the approver check the box to "Defer this release until 1am".

Am I missing something? I feel like there *has* to be a way to do this.

Please let me know if more info is needed!

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another case of a TFS "workaround" being the actual, only way.

We just discovered today yet another caveat to this "defer approval" system: TFS doesn't respect the deferral if several people are required for approval. There were three users required to approve the release. Here's what happened:

1. User A deferred approval to 11PM local time.
2. User B approved release.
3. User C approved release.

1 minute later, the TFS agent began the deployment process.

Luckily it went off without a hitch, but the only solution seems to be to remind everyone to enter the deferred deployment, and perhaps have an extra person on the release to be the designated "last approver". Barely functional.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to not have a pre-deployment approval on the first stage of your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If manual approve is required, the better way is change time when approve (As you said that Defer this release until 1 am), no another better way.

Otherwise, you can specify Automatic approver (Select an environment > Click …>Assign Approvals > Select Automatic)

Comment: So that is actually the only way, since I we do require manual approval? What happens if someone forgets to defer, and it kills our production environment? Obviously that _shouldn't_ happen, but it could.

Comment: You may consider building a service app (e.g. windows service) to check each release definition byusing REST API and send email to related user before sometimes that the release need to be deployed.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I can add this to my long list of reasons to move from TFS :) 
Thanks for clearing that up for me at least!

Comment: You also can submit a uservoice.